# JSF, Primefaces LazyDataModel - select/click an item in a dataTable to view its detail on another page without invoking load method

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hello EveryOne well this is  an example of my lazy dataTable ,   so when i click the command link to view the item detail on another page the load method invoked ,
I want only to go to the detail page without invoking load method - because my data is not changed so there is no need to request database.

```
<h:form id="form"> 
        <div class="card">
    <p:dataTable id="table" var="car" value="#{carBean.lazyCars}" widgetvar="wVar" lazy="true" 
    selection="#{carBeans.selectedCar}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{car.id}">
                <p:column headerText="Code">
                    <h:outputText value="#{product.code}" />
                </p:column>
    
                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{product.name}" />
                </p:column>
    
               <p:column headerText="action">
                   <p:commandLink ajax="false" target="_blank" action="carBeans.details()"
onclick="PF('wVar').unselectAllRows();PF('wVar').selectRow($(this).parents('tr:first'));">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" 
target="#{carBeans.selectedCar}"/>
                   </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

How will this work if you select a car, a new browser tab is opened, you come back to the overview and select a different car? I would keep the UI restricted to a single browser window to prevent selecting different entities and it will allow to use `@ViewScoped` on the bean instead of `@SessionScoped`.

Then, there is no need to set the selected entity using an action as

```html
<p:dataTable selection="#{carBeans.selectedCar}" .../>
```

already takes care of it.

See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Comment: yes my bean is view scoped the problem is load method invoked when  i click the commandLink

Comment: That's the whole point. If you open a new window, your bean cannot be `@ViewScoped`. Don't open a new tab. Instead try something link `p:dialog`.